# Windows 7 Upgrade using Advisor

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from **windows 7 home basic to windows 7 professional**, both 64-bit.

I ran the windows anytime upgrade, which says that my system is really compatible for an upgrade.

The upgrade runs:

```
asks for an upgrade key, 

prompts me to agree the terms and conditions,

continues for a few minutes, and then says it was unsuccessful.
```

When it ran for the first time, it popped an error about the restore points. I corrected

them, and ran it again. This time the upgrade runs, and then pops and error, without specifying what it actually is, and provides me with a link for an on line solution.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: AFAIR the "windows upgrade advisor" is for upgrading XP or Vista to Win7. For changing the Win7 version the "Windows Anytime Upgrade" is used.

Comment: I tried using Windows Anytime Upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

AS Robert says - from the Amazon Windows 7 Anytime upgrade blurb:

*Windows Anytime Upgrade
No disks, no delays. And no leaving the house: 
With Windows Anytime Upgrade, you can upgrade to a more advanced edition of Windows 7 in as little as 10 minutes. That way, you get to take advantage of extra features while keeping your current programs, files, and settings intact.
In the past, upgrading Windows could be a bit of a hassle. In Windows 7, the software you need comes preinstalled. All you have to do is purchase an upgrade key from Microsoft or another authorized retailer to unlock those shiny new features.*

Comment: I tried using Windows Anytime Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this particular failure to do the anytime upgrade means you do Not have Windows 7 Service Pack 1 installed, SP1 must be installed before anytime upgrade will succeed.

Use Windows Update to get it installed.

Control Panel (icon view) > Windows Update > Check for Updates